# How can I make a conditional default mouseleave event?

Tags: jquery, user-interface

This is a corner case I am trying to solve: I have a navigation panel on the left, and a content panel on the right. Mouseenter on each nav item on the left fires a corresponding change to the contents of the right panel. So far so good. The contents contain a link, so we want the user to be able to place their mouse over the right contents panel. BUT if I use a mouseleave event on each nav, then every move to the right loses the custom content and fires the default content. If I have NO mouseleave events, the interaction is good, it is OK to leave the last content panel up...except for certain non-nav exits that have no mouseenter defined... which leaves the content panel blank. For those I want the default content, but in a catchall way. I need a command like: "watch for the next mouseenter event, and if you don't see one, uh, panic and put up the default content!"